# Example when this is not equal sets: $B \subseteq f^{-1}(f(B))$

Tags: real-analysis

I cannot come up with an examples for the following.

Suppose that this is a function: $f:X\rightarrow Y$. And let $B \subseteq X$.

Then how is it possible for the following to hold (not in the equality sense, i.e. in the sense that $B$ may be a smaller set than $f^{-1}(f(B))$:

$$B \subseteq f^{-1}(f(B))$$.

I cannot come up with anything. I have drawn a doodle where I have domain $X$ and within it, there is some area $B$ and then when I apply function $f$ to that area, it takes me to some area in $Y$, now $f^{-1}(f(B))$ simply unwinds my application of the function, so in theory it should take me right back to the original set $B$?

Comment: Try $f$ constant.

Comment: To echo Liuz, many points, not necessarily in $B$ may map into $f(B)$.

Comment: Oh yes, because this may be a surjective function.

Comment: any function that is not 1-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take

$$X=\mathbb R$$

$$B=(0,+\infty)$$

$$f(x)=x^2$$

then

$$f(B)=(0,+\infty)$$

$$f^{-1}(f(B))=(-\infty,0)\cup (0,+\infty)$$

Comment: ahhhhhh. I see now. Thanks